# Tagging library for Android

Tags: android

I have an app where users upload contents. I want to allow the user to tag these contents just like the tagging system works here on stack over flow.

Is there a library to help with it. so that after typing a word and pressing space or comma, it will make that word into a little button with the word and a smaller little button to remove the tag just like in stackoverflow?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/chips-text-fields/ and https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library offer the "chips UI", though you would have to handle deletions more yourself.